# OOP class can not write to file because is_writable returns false

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning PHP Object Oriented Programming and tried to read and write data from a file. But it doesn't create the file at all and gives me an error message:

> Change your chmod to test.txt

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
class log
{
    public function Write($strFileName, $strData)
    {
        if (!is_writable($strFileName))
        die("Change your chmod to ".$strFileName);

        $handle = fopen($strFileName,'a+');
        fwrite($handle,"\r".$strData);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    public function Read($strFileName)
    {
        $handle = fopen($strFileName,'r');
        return file_get_contents($strFileName);
    }
}
$log = new log();
$log->Write('test.txt','Hello World!');
?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error message?

Comment: Change your chmod to test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `file_put_contents` with `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` flags, simplify your code and make sure the file is properly locked and unlocked.

Also you dont need a handle for opening the file as file_get_contents handles the opening and closing on its own.

```
<?php 
class log
{
    public function Write($strFileName, $strData)
    {
        file_put_contents($strFileName, $strData, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    public function Read($strFileName)
    {
        return file_get_contents($strFileName);
    }
}
$log = new log();
$log->Write('test.txt','Hello World!');
?>
```

And while we are learning OOD, the filename should be contained within the class since it is constant to the log object created, saves clutter when using the object and reading/writing to it:

```
<?php 
class log
{
    public $logFilePath;
    public function __construct($logFilePath) {
        $this->logFilePath = $logFilePath;
    }
    public function Write($strData)
    {
        file_put_contents($this->logFilePath, $strData, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    public function Read()
    {
        return file_get_contents($this->logFilePath);
    }
}
$log = new log('test.txt');
$log->Write('Hello World!');
echo $log->Read();
?>
```

Comment: You didn't use my code as that error isn't in there, its because you are trying to test if a file that does not exist is writable, if the file does not exist then it cannot be writeable and you will always get that error.